# SQL 2019 CU13 breaks Cluster_nodename

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, dmv

With total disregard to my paranoia about this unlucky number we installed CU 13 for SQL 2019 in one of our environments (in defense of the number 13 I have the same issue with 14). The progression was CU11 to CU13 and the issue we're noticing seems to be affecting `sys.dm_server_services`, returning incorrect characters for `cluster_nodename`.

Has anyone else gone to CU13 (or 14) and experienced the same issue? We have a ticket open with MS but I'm curious if the SQL Gods are singling us out for some past transgression.

[image]

Same results using sqlcmd. While running under CU11 the value reflects the proper value; after installing CU13 (or 14) it shows the new chars. The node name is alpha-numeric with a hyphen.

Answer (score 3):

**Note: This has been fixed in SQL Server 2019 CU19 and SQL Server 2022 RTM. It will not be ported to any previous versions.**

This is an artifact of fixing some items with that DMV. It should be fixed in a future version. I'll update the answer with the version, when available.

I took a deeper look at it today, I see the issue and there isn't anything you can do. It'll need to be fixed in a later version, CU14 should exhibit the same behavior.